# What data type (Article, Book Reviews, Product, etc) should I use for online course?

Tags: schema.org, google-search-console

On https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/ what data type should I use for an online course (such as https://www.udemy.com/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/)?

If I chose the closest, say Book Reviews, will Google think my online course is a book review instead?

Answer (score 0):

The types [`Course`](http://pending.schema.org/Course) and [`CourseInstance`](http://pending.schema.org/CourseInstance) are currently in the pending extension ([discussion about the terms](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/195)), and they will likely be published (i.e., moved to core) in the next Schema.org release (3.2).

If you don’t want to wait, you could use [`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) for specific course instances, and [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) for the creative work behind the course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [doku](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/courses) for courses from Google.